# When values below zero, return as zero

Tags: spotfire

I have a calculated column which has some negative values, how can I make values below zero be returned as 0 only?

Here is what I tried:

```
case
when [Date] - DateTimeNow() > "0" then "0"

else  [Date] - DateTimeNow()

end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you calculate simply [Date]-DateTimeNow() you will see it is returned as type TimeSpan, which is neither a number nor a string. So in your case statement what you are effectively doing is defining a result of two different types (string when “0" and TimeSpan otherwise) depending on the condition (which compares a TimeSpan to a string), which will not work.

This will output a TimeSpan:

```
 case  
   when LongInteger([Date] - DateTimeNow())>0 then TimeSpan(“0.0:0:0.0")
   else [Date] - DateTimeNow()
 end
```

Gaia